# ZSH - Oh My Zsh: modify PROMPT

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to modify the PROMPT variable to include some additional information. My current PROMPT also includes git status on the right hand side. It looks like this:

```
ex2 ➤                                                      git:master*
```

Screen shot of the same:
[image: Screen shot of the same]

I would like to some text in front of the current folder-- like [Drone] for example. I am currently doing it as follows,

```
export PROMPT=%{"$fg[green] [Donre]"$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%c ➤ %{$reset_color%}
```

But this creates two issues.
1. The arrow character is not parsed correctly anymore and I get an error like

```
" not valid in this context: ➤"
```

2. The git status is pushed to the next line. 
The new prompt appears as,

```
 /home/arul/.zshrc:export:100: not valid in this context: ➤
 [Drone]ex2              git:maste
 r*
```

Screen shot of the same:
[image: Screen shot of the same]

Could someone help me in modifying the PROMPT correctly?

Comment: Could you replace the images by actual copy-pasted text (in a code block). This is barely readable (and certainly unreadable for visually impaired people).

Comment: Added text along with the screenshots.

Comment: People who are downvoting, could you please lemme know the reason for downvoting. I am not against you downvoting but if you don't write the reason for downvoting, there is no way that I could improve the question here. I am not sure if the downvote is due to the way the question is presented or the actual question itself. I happy to get downvotes if at the end I get the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{...}` does not escape any spaces contained therein; you should quote the *entire* value to ensure any enclosed whitespace is properly escaped for the assignment.

```
export PROMPT="%{$fg[green] [Donre]$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%c ➤ %{$reset_color%}"
```

As is, the arrow character is being treated as a separate argument (and an invalid parameter name at that) to the `export` command. `export`, by the way, is probably unnecessary. Each shell that needs the value of `PROMPT` is likely executing whatever configuration file contains this assignment.

---

Consider using `zsh`'s own support for colors, so that you don't need `%{...}` at all.

```
PROMPT="%F{green} [Donre]%F{...}%c ➤ %f"
```

(where `...` is whatever color `$NCOLOR` represents).

Comment: I don't get the error anymore. But the GIT status appearing at the right-hand side is getting pushed to next line. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I don't see anything that might cause that. What is the value of `RPROMPT`?

Comment: %{$fg[$NCOLOR]%}%p $(git_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}
This is the default value of the RPROMPT before me making any changes to the PROMPT variable.

Comment: The string returned by `git_prompt_info` may contain characters that need to be enclosed in `%{...%}`. Again, it's probably better to use `zsh`'s VCS facilities than to use a function designed for `bash`.